# Recommendations for A/B Testings a block/template

Tags: template, forms, ce-1.9.2.2, google-analytics, testing

I have a form on my site for customers to request a quote on a product. The form is stored in a template file. I want to test two versions of this form. One form would ask the user to enter their email. The second form would not. Ideally I'd like to have two separate template files and A/B test the two files. The file is stored in `app/design/frontend/default/.../form.phtml`. The other file would be in the same directory.

Is there a plugin or the likes that can handle this sort of a/b testing?

Comment: Please add your magento version as a tag to your question.